AutoHotKey 2.0 Error: Warning: This local variable appears to never be assigned a value
This is my first time writing an AHK script for my new split keyboard. I'm familiar with coding but not specifically with AHK syntax.
Here's the relevant part of the script:
; Left Space (SC039) is the trigger key, no hold required
~SC039::
{

    ; Wait for the next key press
    userKey:= Input("L1 T5")
    ; Show MsgBox with the pressed key for debugging
    MsgBox("Key pressed after trigger: " userKey)

    ; If Backspace is pressed, exit the macro sequence
    if (userKey = "Backspace")
    {
        MsgBox("Backspace pressed, exiting the macro.")
        return  ; Ends the macro and stops further key processing
    }
    else if (userKey = "n")
    {
        ; Trigger: Open new window of current focused window
        MsgBox("Trigger: Open new window of current focused window")
    } ... etc

And here's the error I get when I run the script:
Warning: This local variable appears to never be assigned a value.

Specifically: Input

    006: {
▶   009: userKey := Input("L1 T5")
    011: MsgBox("Key pressed after trigger: " userKey)
    014: If (userKey = "Backspace")

For more details, read the documentation for #Warn.

I can provide the full script if it's helpful, or any other info.
I altered the Input line from
Input, userKey, L1
(which I believe is 1.1?) to
Input(userKey, "L1")
at the behest of ChatGPT.
That still didn't work, so I tried assigning the userKey variable directly with
userKey:= Input("L1")
and added "T5" to see if the time constraint was an issue. Ideally I want it to wait until another key is pressed, though, not have a time limit.

In AutoHotkey V2, the input handling mechanism has been significantly updated with the introduction of InputHook(). This new method replaces the previous input approach in AHK, offering more powerful and flexible input capture capabilities. For AHK developers, this change provides enhanced control over input processing and makes it easier to create complex input-related scripts.
Key improvements include:

More robust input capturing
Greater flexibility in handling user inputs
Improved method for creating custom input scenarios
Enhanced programmatic control over input events

For detailed implementation and usage, developers should refer to the official AutoHotkey V2 documentation on InputHook(), which provides comprehensive guidance on leveraging this new input method effectively.
